# What's the use of .cmd in Git Bash?

Tags: git-bash

What's the use of using `.cmd` appended to a command like `gatsby.cmd` or `yarn.cmd` in Git Bash?

Answer (score 0):

You can run an `.exe`, `.bat` or `.cmd` from a [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) bash session.

But you can also run them from a CMD.
That means, having both yarn and yarn.cmd give you two options:

- native bash (shell, no extension)
- CMD-compatible (.cmd)